# Really simple CSS Site

Tags: html, css, web

I am trying to teach myself web design, and I find it amusing that I can code in C and C++ but can't make a website. I'm trying to do something really simple. I have made my header image 234 pixels high and 1 pixel wide. I can make it repeat, but how do I get it to repeat the whole way across the screen and not go past that point and have a sideway scroll bar? I have tried giving it a width in the CSS style sheet however that is the reason behind the need to scroll. I have seen it is possible with Javascript, but am trying to avoid that at the minute.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you remove margin/padding from body

```
body {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Then add your header div inside the body element with this css

```
#header {
    height: 234px;
    background-image: url('images/header.png');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

Then the header should span all across the site without making scrollbars anywhere. Divs have `width: 100%` by default.

Comment: +1 for remembering to change the body defaults for this question.

Comment: Thanks, I just had a few extra bits in it that wasnt letting it work out. One other question, I have what can only be described as some kind of boarder on the page, maybe 3px each way, is there a simple line to remove this?

Comment: Yeah, It must be something else im doing in dreamweaver I have the header inside of the wrapper divs and the wrapper is set as padding 0 and margin 0. Thanks for your help man!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you've tried but what you're describing sounds like the repeat-x CSS property. Try that after looking it up--I use it quite a bit in a similiar manner to what you're describing.